# Server running on guest Linux VM will not accept connections from Windows host

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, socket

I have a simple echo server program running on CentOS 7. If I run both the client and the server in the VM, I can connect to the server.

I'm using VirtualBox with the "bridged" network configuration. Using the IP of my Linux VM (found using ifconfig), I can successfully ssh into the Linux VM from Cygwin in Windows.

However when I try to connect to the server using putty from my Windows 7 host PC the connection won't work. I don't understand why the server doesn't see a connection request from the host PC. What could be causing this? The windows Firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was CentOS 7 blocking ports by default. I managed to connect to my server on port 2004 after executing the following command:

firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2004/tcp

And this command opens the port when the VM reboots:

firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2004/tcp --permanent

I found the information [here](http://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=28348).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely if the server is available and you have an IP address for that server you should be able to

```
ssh user@server-ip or ssh server-ip -l user
```

but this will not work if you don't have sshd running on the server to accept ssh/secured tunneling. You need to enable sshd on your server by issuing:

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/sshd start
```

You should also look at your

```
 sudo tail -f /var/log/secure
```

to determine what's going on with ssh when you try to attempt a ssh connection via putty or from a Linux/UNIX terminal.

Comment: Yep, like I said I can ssh from Cygwin so I know the host PC can "see" the VM. At first I thought it could be a blocked port on the host PC but it seems like the problem might be a blocked port on the VM.

Comment: hmn. then you should go to VBox, right click on your Linux instance, go to Network -> Under Adapter 1 -> click Advanced -> then go to Port Forwarding. Then add your port rules there.

Answer (score 0):

Some consumer-grade routers are confused by the bridged mode of VirtualBox, because then the host and the guest share the same MAC address. I suggest you add a second interface to your VM in host-only mode, for communcation with the host.